# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus - Need Confirmation of my answer?

Tags: calculus, integration

*Not homework, just extra practice.

Find $g'(x)$ given that

$$g(x) = \int_3^{x^4}   t \sqrt{2+t} dt.$$

... If I understand it correctly, would I simply replace the $t$'s with $x^4$, so

$$g'(x) = x^4 \sqrt{2 + x^4} (4x^3)$$

If not, what am I doing wrong? Not really comfortable with integrals yet.

Comment: You are correct. I guess you understand you are using Chain rule here?

Comment: Yes, that's right. An easy mistake to make is to forget about the Chain Rule (the $4x^3$ term). You did not make that mistake.

Comment: I wasn't confident, but I took a guess, yeah. I'm surprised it's correct, to be perfectly honest - I felt as though I was definitely missing a step or two.

Comment: If you had needed the derivative of say $\int_{\sin x}^{x^4}f(t)\,dt$, the result would be $4x^3f(x^4)-(\cos x)f(\sin x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct.

Consider;
$$g(x) = \int f(x) dx$$
This means:
$$g'(x)=f(x)$$

Then:
$$\int_{b(x)}^{a(x)}  f(t) dt=g(a(x))-g(b(x))$$

So:
$${d\over dx}\int_{b(x)}^{a(x)}   f(t) dt={d\over dx}g(a(x))-{d\over dx}g(b(x))$$

By the chain rule this is:
$$a'(x)g'(a(x))-b'(x)g'(b(x))=a'(x)f(a(x))-b'(x)f(b(x))$$

In your example $b(x)=3$ so $b'(x)=0$ 
Now sub in $f(t)=t\sqrt{2+t}, \; a(x)=x^4, \; a'(x)=4x^3$

To get:
$$4x^3(x^4\sqrt{2+x^4})=4x^7\sqrt{x^4+2}$$